# Intervention Image - Reducing image size gradually

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm trying to reduce the size of the images uploaded by users on a project I'm working on. The main idea is to resize the image down by 10%, and checking if its size is under a set requirement.

Here is my code: (`$optimisedImage` is the original image uploaded by the user and recieved from the request)

```php
$optimisedImage->save("user_uploads/" . $scrollFeedName);
$scrollFeedImg = Image::make("user_uploads/" . $scrollFeedName);
        
while(filesize("user_uploads/" . $scrollFeedName) > 1000000) {
    $scrollFeedImg->resize(floor($scrollFeedImg->width() * 0.9), floor($scrollFeedImg->height() * 0.9));
    $scrollFeedImg->save();
}
```

Currently there seems to be an issue with the loop, getting stuck. I also tried the Intervention Image `filesize()`, but was getting an error stating that the `width` or `heigth` need to be higher than 0.

Is there any way to achieve my goal, or are there better solutions to that problem?

Stack:

- PHP: **8.1.10**
- Laravel: **9.19**

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm not entirely sure that the approach I've taken is the correct one. Also I've not used PHP that much and may be doing a trivial mistake which I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Install intervention for resize image

```
composer require intervention/image
```

**Step 2:** Add provider path and alias path in `config/app.php`

```
return [
    $provides => [
        'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
    ],
    $aliases => [
        'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
    ]
];
```

**Step 3:** Resize Image code for controller

```
public function resizeImagePost(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
  
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     
        $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');
        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);
   
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
   
        $this->postImage->add($input);
   
        return back()
            ->with('success','Image Upload successful')
            ->with('imageName',$input['imagename']);
    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response, however I need to create an image that has the highest possible resolution while still being under 1MB. Your solution is going to work, but the image will be too small.